# Recursive search for sql files in directories (NSIS)

Tags: nsis

I have a problem with recursive search, but first some key data:

- I have several directories filled with sql files which I want to copy to $TEMP
- the directories i want to read from look like this v2.1.0.0
- at the moment, the directories v2.5.0.0 to v2.7.0.3 have to be read
- folders dont have to be "the next" so v2.5.0.3 can follow v2.5.0.0
- I'm using the LogicLib
- I'm new to this language (before java) and this is my first task

I'm currently trying to solve the problem with a ${ForEach}

```
!macro GetSQLVersionFiles first second third fourth
SetOutPath $TEMP
${ForEach} ${first} 0 9 + 1
    ${ForEach} ${second} 0 9 + 1
        ${ForEach} ${third} 0 9 + 1
            ${ForEach} ${fourth} 0 9 + 1
            IfFileExists "scripte\v${first}.${second}.${third}.${fourth}" 0 +2
            File "scripte\v${first}.${second}.${third}.${fourth}\*.sql"
            ${next}
        ${next}
    ${next}
${next}
!macroend
```

so my idea was, to make it viable for later, to have a macro with 4 parameters in which one can put the start directory, say the desired "2 5 0 0" and it iterates through every folder and puts the found .sql files into the $TEMP directory

things i've already tried

- refering to all parameters without the {}
- writing "${first} ${first} 9 + 1 (thought this would only iterate FROM first to 9)

the error i get is following

```
!insertmacro: _ForEach
Usage: StrCpy $(user_var: output) str [maxlen] [startoffset]
Error in macro _ForEach on macroline 3
Error in macro GetSQLVersionFiles on macroline 2
Error in script "\\NAMEOFMYSCRIPT -- aborting creation process
```

the third line in _ForEach of the LogicLib is

```
StrCpy "${_v}" "${_f}"                                ; Assign the initial value
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing defines and variables.

Defines are created with `!define` and accessed with `${name}`.

Variables are created with `Var` and accessed with `$name`. There are also some built in variables you can use: $0..$9.

Variables can be changed at run-time, defines cannot.

The other issue is that you cannot use the `File` instruction to copy files on the end-users machine, you need to use the `CopyFiles` instruction if you want to copy files at run-time. If on the other hand you want to extract files from the installer (I cannot tell which you want based on your question) then you do need to use the `File` instruction but then you cannot use `${For}` because it is a run-time concept. You can use `!system` to [execute a batch file that builds a list of files in a .nsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437253/nsis-how-to-recursively-include-all-files-only-from-source-folder-and-subfolde) that you then `!include`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I wanted to do the second, extract files from the installer.
I guess I will start looking into batch then, thank you!