# Pass a variable into File function in for loop cycle in NSIS

Tags: file, for-loop, nsis

my problem is this:
I cannot pass variable inside a for loop, it seems that it does not recognize the variable. It takes the string with the variable, but not the variable value.
This is my code

```
!define FORMAT "XY 2018|XY 2019"

!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Explode.nsh"

# set the name of the installer
Outfile "example.exe"

# create a default section.
Section

${Explode}  $0  "|" "${FORMAT}"
${For} $1 1 $0
    Pop $2
    !define PATH_OK "Z:\XY\Doc\List\*$2*"
    File "${PATH_OK}"
${Next}

SectionEnd
```

When I'm going to compile the nsis file, it returns this error:

```
!define: "PATH_OK"="Z:\XY\Doc\List\*$2*"
File: "Z:\XY\Doc\List\*$2*" -> no files found.
Usage: File [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec [...]] filespec [...] |
/oname=outfile one_file_only)
Error in script "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\example.nsi" on line 19 aborting creation process
```

I can't understand why... if I try to change the code File "${PATH_OK}" with a messagebox the path result ok. Where am I doing wrong?
Many thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix and match compile-time and run-time instructions! You should also learn the difference between a `${define}` and a `$variable`.

All instructions starting with `!` are processed by the [pre-processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor). On the other hand, `${For}` runs on the end-users machine and that is too late for `File` to add files to your installer.

`File` only supports basic DOS wildcards (`*` and `?`):

```
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "c:\mysourcefiles\XY 201?.txt"
SectionEnd
```

If you need something more advanced then you must use a macro or [a external helper program executed with `!system`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36437539).

```
!define FORMAT "XY 2018.txt|XY 2019.txt"

!macro ExplodeAndIncludeFile string sep
!searchparse /noerrors "${string}" "" ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp "${sep}"
!ifdef ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp
    File "${ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp}"
    !undef ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp
    !searchparse /noerrors "${string}" "${sep}" ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp
    !ifdef ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp
        !insertmacro ${__MACRO__} "${ExplodeAndIncludeFile_Temp}" "${sep}" ; Macro recursion only supported in NSIS 3+
    !endif
!endif
!macroend

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
!insertmacro ExplodeAndIncludeFile "${FORMAT}" "|"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an illegal character (*) in the file name.

Reference:
[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I cannot think the problem is that. I tried to remove the wildcard but the response is always the same: `File: "Z:\T_CAD\Documentazione\Listini\$2" -> no files found.`

Answer (score 0):

`!define` is a compile time command, while variables are defined and evaluated at runtime.

From the [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#compcommands):

> #### Compiler Utility Commands
>
> These commands are similar to the C preprocessor in terms of purpose
>   and functionality. They allow file inclusion, conditional compilation,
>   executable header packing and process execution during the build
>   process. **Note: None of these commands allow the use of variables.**

Also, unlike defines, variables don't work with the `File` command.

Comment: This answer does not really solve the problem, should really be a comment?